# .htaccess and double quotations in url

Tags: php

I get the 404 error when i click on the hyperlink due to the quotation marks.  The MySQL column `title` has this value `the official "i'm hungry" page`

```
$title = str_replace(' ','-',$row['title']);
<a href='/page/$id/$title'>click me</a>
```

Here is the url without modrewrite `http://localhost/page.php&id=7&p=the-official-"i'm-hungry"-page`

The modrewrite changes the url to `http://localhost/page/7/the-official-"i'm-hungry"-page` but the link isn't working.

Here is the rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?$ /page.php?id=$1&p=$2 [L]`

How do i fix this, so i don't get the 404 error?

Comment: Why not change the Page Name to something legal?

Comment: Since you're already replacing spaces, I would recommend also removing the quotes.

Comment: You should URL encode to ensure that variables are legal in your variable. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @Brant what do you mean legal? Are quotations not allowed in url?  How do you recommend i do urls when the title has quotations.

Comment: Quotations are invalid URI Chars, here's what's valid: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you want to identify your pages by their ID, not by their title. Clients will always try to add bizarre characters, such as `"`, `/`, `'`, and `&`, to their page titles. These characters can break links.

http://example.com/page/1234/the+official+"i'm+hungry"/"i'm+thirsty"+page

This rewrite rule should collect the page's ID, then add anything else as a second variable:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /page.php?id=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

If you do this, then the title becomes purely cosmetic, and you can add stricter filters to prevent unexpected behavior (for example, if a user creates and page named `the official "i'm hungry"/"i'm thirsty" page`, you can convert it to `the-official-i-m-hungry-i-m-thirsy-page` in the URL without affecting the content of your webpage.

For example, both of these links take you to the same place:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864634/htaccess-and-double-quotations-in-url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864634/gibberishgibberishgibberish
```

If you want to force users to the page with the correct title, then you can update `page.php` to fetch the ID from the URL, then redirect the user to the correct, cosmetically appropriate URL. For example:

```
<?php
function ConvertTitle($title)
{
    // Replace all non-alphanumeric characters with a dash (-)
    return preg_replace($title, '%[^A-z0-9]+%', '-');
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$title = getArticleTitleById($id);

//  If the title isn't correct
if(ConvertTitle($title) != ConvertTitle($_GET['p'])
{
    //  Send the user to the correct Cosmetic URL, StackOverflow does something like this
    $url = '/page/'.$id.'/'. ConvertTitle($title);
    header("location: $url");
} 

// load the page as normal
?>
```

However, as long as you load content by the Page's ID, not the name, then it should work correctly even with an incorrect URL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `str_replace` you have used, use a `preg_replace` to strip out anything but letters and numbers from the `$title` and replace that with a `-`